# Max date in R column with sapply

Tags: r, max, sapply

I am trying to use sapply to get the max date in a column but it is returning a number instead of a date.  Any idea how to resolve this?  I can't seem to figure out why this is occurring..

```
 mtcars$datecolm = '2015-03-03'
 mtcars$datecolm[1] = '2015-09-09'
  mtcars$datecolm = as.Date(mtcars$datecolm)

    sapply(mtcars, max)   # why is it returning a number instead of a date??
    max(mtcars$datecolm)   # works correctly
```

Please use sapply given the way I have set this up...    I know this works with apply(mtcars,2,max).

Comment: to convert numeric date form into a readable date form, just transform your datecolm column data. e.g. `as.Date(16687, origin="1970-01-01")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `lapply` instead of `sapply`

```
lapply(mtcars, max)
```

as `sapply` returns a `vector` because of the `simplify=TRUE` default argument and `vector` can hold only a single class.  As there are numeric columns, the 'Date' column (which is stored as integer) gets coerced to `integer` value.  However, we can still use `sapply` if we use `simplify = FALSE` to return a `list`.

```
sapply(mtcars, max, simplify = FALSE)
```

Regarding the use of `apply`

```
apply(mtcars,2,max)
```

I would not recommend using `apply` as this will convert to matrix and matrix can hold only a single class.  Here, it will be all `character` output as the 'Date' class got converted to `character`.

---

Regarding the problem mentioned by OP in the comments, when we have output that belong to different class, we could either use `list` or `data.frame` (as `data.frame` is a `list`) as `c` i.e. concatenate returns a `vector` and as mentioned above, it can hold only a single class.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(mtcars, function(x) 
          data.frame(Class=class(x), Max=max(x, na.rm=TRUE))))
```

Comment: I tried using something like this  and it doesnt work - ---as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, function(x) c(class(x), max(x, na.rm=TRUE))))

Comment: @runningbirds  I updated the post with the problem you mentioned